# React Bootstrap collapsible navbar not working

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I've been having issues with making my React app work on mobile, notably the bootstrap navbar. The burger menu shows up, but on clicking it the nav items don't display. Here's what I have so far:

### Relevant code

app.js

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
            RPA
          </a>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <NavLink
                  className="nav-link"
                  exact
                  to="/"
                  activeClassName="active"
                >
                  example
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <NavLink
                  to="/about"
                  className="nav-link"
                  activeClassName="active"
                >
                  example
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <NavLink
                  to="/subreddit_list"
                  className="nav-link"
                  activeClassName="active"
                >
                  example
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="nav-link"
                  href=""
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                  example
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

### Expected vs actual outcome

Ideally, the navbar would open and close on mobile, but currently its just gray and highlights when clicked on, not expanding.

### What I tried

1. Followed this thread [related to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61321765/bootstrap-navbar-in-react-app-not-working-on-mobile-view) and adding those scripts didn't seem to affect my code.
2. Imported jquery, no effect
3. Considered a different career, no effect

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. I can't figure this out right now by myself unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: Check this out and I hope it helps. Also check the codesandbox in my details.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67529409/react-router-on-how-to-collapse-the-navbar-on-mobile-when-selecting-the-menu-lin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use `react-bootstrap` for ReactJS projects.

Here is a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/implementing-navbar-react-bootstrap-r3xsj) for making a Navbar responsive and collapsive with the burguer icon.

Please check de depndencies and the imports on js files.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Container, Navbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
export const AppNavbar = () => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Navbar expanded={expanded} bg="light" expand="lg">
      <Container fluid>
        <Navbar.Brand>Bookkeeping</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle
          aria-controls="navbarScroll"
          onClick={() => setExpanded(expanded ? false : "expanded")}
        />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
          <Nav className="me-auto my-2 my-lg-0" navbarScroll>
            <Link
              to="/"
              className="nav-link"
              onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}
            >
              Home
            </Link>
            <Link
              to="expenses"
              className="nav-link"
              onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}
            >
              Expenses
            </Link>
            <Link
              to="invoices"
              className="nav-link"
              onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}
            >
              Invoices
            </Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

in main.js or whatever your main react component of your project you should import two bootstrap models

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
```

because bootstrap events handled by bootstrap.js file in bootstrap library